# iOS7 How to Capture an Image and add a Caption

Tags: image, ios7, camera, xcode5, caption

Using Xcode 5 and Developing for iOS7  How can I capture an image add a caption and then store it within an app to be retrieved and displayed on a separate view controller within the app.

I know you set this code

```
- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
           usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                               UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
             UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil))
        return NO;


    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Displays a control that allows the user to choose picture or
    // movie capture, if both are available:
    cameraUI.mediaTypes =
    [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;

    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];
    return YES;
}
```

But how do I then caption the image save it a retrieve it on another view controller, would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am not wrong, There is no in build property or API for adding caption in image.
First you have to capture image using `UIImagePickerController` after capturing image use your `UIViewcontroller` that shows image and put there `UITextfield` to add caption , and then after save it.

Or You can use Overlay property of `UIImagePickerController` you can try with it.